# How to display user input as a chat bubble using simple javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I'm developing a chatbox and I have the chat messages hardcoded for the moment.

```
                    <!-- Reciever Message-->
                <div class="media w-50 ml-auto mb-3">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <div class="bg-primary rounded py-2 px-3 mb-2">
                            <p class="text-small mb-0 text-white">Test chat</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I have a form with a simple input box.

```
     <form action="#" class="bg-light">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Type a message" aria-describedby="button-addon2" class="form-control rounded-0 border-0 py-4" id="message">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button id="button-addon2" type="submit" class="btn btn-link" onclick="addText()"> <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

What I want is a way to display the text entered in the text box as the receive message div when the form is submitted. Any suggestions as to how to do it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is really a design question, not a technical one.  Technically speaking you just do exactly what you are doing ... and then put a "chat bubble graphic" as the `background-image` style of `.bg-light`.

Comment: I implemented a function to create the required elements, but it's not getting displayed. I'll edit the question with the new code.

Comment: Each "actual question" on Stack Overflow should be its own Stack Overflow question.  If you edit this one you're unlikely to get an answer, so I'd advise starting a new one instead.

Comment: Okay I'll open a new question